# How can I get T4MVC to regenerate the .generated.cs files?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, t4mvc

I am adding tests to the NerdDinner DinnersController class, and when I create the constructors needed to do Constructor Injection I get a conflict with the T4MVC-generated constructor (specifically, the base constructor).  It looks like the base constructor is not generated if one already exists -- is this true?  If so, what do I need to do to re-generate the T4MVC files?

Thanks,
Dave

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Right-click on the `T4MVC.tt` file in Solution Explorer, then click Run Custom Tool.  This will regenerate the files.

Answer (score 2):

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=BennorMcCarthy.AutoT4MVC

Click the link above, or if it disappears, in Visual Studio (2015):

1. Click Tools
2. Click Extensions and Updates
3. On the right, search for `AutoT4MVC`
4. Install, and restart VS

Your templates should now rebuild automatically every time you build.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/14858943)

Comment: Yea, I know. But what can I do? Post up a mirror? The answer is "Using this extension."

Comment: the answer would rather have been an *example* as to *how*

Comment: You want me to guide him through installing an extension. Fine.