# T4MVC - how to re-generate?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, t4mvc

I've installed [T4MVC](http://t4mvc.codeplex.com/) via NuGet.

At the point of installation, it generated the helper classes for the project as the project was at that time. However, these generated helper classes have not been updating whenever new items have been added to the project.

Several people have had this problem and the answer always seems to be "right-click on the T4MVC.tt file and choose *Run custom tool*" (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5238848/how-can-i-get-t4mvc-to-regenerate-the-generated-cs-files) for an example). However, when I right-click on the T4MVC.tt file there's no *Run custom tool* option - in fact, in the file's properties there's no Custom Tool declared.

Furthermore, T4MVC.tt is a hidden file in the project, so it seems strange that I'm expected to perform this action on this file.

So can anyone explain how to have T4MVC update the generated classes in an MVC4 project?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

there are a couple of Visual studio plugins which will autorun the template when you do a build. I use
[AutoT4MVC](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/8d820b76-9fc4-429f-a95f-e68ed7d3111a)

However it sounds like your solution has an issue with the template, youcould try right clicking and excluding the file from the project and then right click and add it back? (this requires you to set the option "show all files"). Alternatively you could uninstall t4mvc and then readd it. Also the setting in tools/options/text templating should allow you to see that dialog if its gone missing.
Hope this helps

Comment: I've now installed AutoT4MVC, but there's no difference: the generated classes are not affected in any way when I add a new view or build.  I've also uninstalled and then reinstalled the T4MVC NuGet package... but still nothing happens.

Comment: Just a thought: the generated classes don't have to be already checked-out of source control, no?

Comment: @awj in my environment, any changed classes auto check out when newer versions of them are created by the tt template. i.e. if i manually rerun the template (right click ) or i do a build.

Comment: As per @Tim's advice, I uninstalled and reinstalled the T4MVC NuGet package (after having AutoT4MVC installed) and it works.

There are a couple of other differences between the first installation and this: the T4MVC.tt file was previously hidden (not anymore) and the generated classes were all visible at the top level of the project, whereas these are now 'buddy files' of the T4MVC.tt file.